# Tengo un problema con ruby

Tags: ruby

Soy nuevo en ruby, 
al momento de cerrar sesión no me redirreciona 
mi pagina al login alguien sabe porque?

Estoy usando la gema de devise para hacer el login

*Gracias*

Comment: Bienvenido Angel, deberías poner el código que tienes actualmente sino es imposible ayudarte. Pásate por el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) y revisa las secciones [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Después [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/240529/edit) tu pregunta y añade toda la información que sea posible.

Comment: Agrega información de logging del servidor (copiar-pegar, no pantallazo). Muestra tu archivo de rutas. ¿a que página te está redireccionando? ¿has hecho alguna modificación sobre los controladores de devise? si la has hecho, también agrégalo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Pon esto en el application_controller y debería hacértelo automáticamente:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Esto obliga al usuario a estar logueado para poder utilizar cualquier parte de la aplicación, por lo que al acceder, sino está logueado, le redirecciona al login. Igualmente si cierra sesión.